# Threads with UI (Canvas)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls

I'm trying to generate a Thread for the redrawing-function of my existing poly-drawing. I read here it is possible that UI can be realized in Threads see here [LINK](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/) but I cant use it on my redrawSingelPoly() function.... Any ideas how I can use redrawSingelPoly() as an thread ?

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

Is called when the user press a button on my main window:

```
    private void SingleSelectedMeasurement(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Button button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
        RedrawSingelMeasurement(Convert.ToInt16(button.Tag));
    }

    private void RedrawSingelMeasurement(int selectedMeasurement)
    {
        selectedMeasurement = selectedMeasurement - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < measurements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (selectedMeasurement != i) 
            {
                measurements[i].draw = false; //block drawing
            }
            else
            {
                measurements[i].draw = true; // remove block for drawing
            }
        }
            measurements[selectedMeasurement].redrawSingelPoly(); 
    }
```

In my Measurement.cs:

```
    public void redrawSingelPoly() 
    {
        Polyline poly = new Polyline();
        poly.Stroke = colorBrush; 
        poly.StrokeThickness = basicLineThick;

        //first clean all
        coordinateSystem.Children.Clear(); 

        poly.Points = points;
        //draw
        coordinateSystem.Children.Add(poly);
    }
```

Comment: Wrap the method in an `Action` delegate and pass it to the UI's dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to DependencyProperties of DependencyObject (in your case: coordinateSystem) from the thread different to the one it's related to.

If you want to speed up your application, you should create custom control, override its OnRender method and draw your custom graphics there: it will remove a lot of logical and visual tree logic and will work a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally one window only can run on one Dispatcher, however you can put different visuals in different threads by HostVisual but in very limited scenarios. Maybe this article can help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What the article you mention talks about is actually just having **one thread for each window**. Drawing dedicated elements in a different thread is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SingleSelectedMeasurement(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;

    Task.Factory.StartNew (
       () => OnUi(RedrawSingelMeasurement(Convert.ToInt16(button.Tag))));        
}

//here's a sample on how to get despatcher for the ui thread
private void OnUi (Action action)
    {
        if (_dispatchService == null) 
            _dispatchService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDispatchService>();
            //or _dispatchService  = Application.Current.Dispatcher - whatever is suitable

        if (_dispatchService.CheckAccess())
            action.Invoke ();
        else
            _dispatchService.Invoke(action);
    }
```

Comment: How I declare this _dispatchService ?